# How do I export web application and site collections structure to production environment without deploying?

Tags: deployment, 2013, infrastructure, cross-site-publishing

Microsoft tells us (yet again) that no custom code is needed in the new version of Sharepoint. However I'm curious how to export Web Application(s) | Site Collection(s) and Site(s) structure including navigation and style to a production site? Is that even possible, and if so what steps are required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you can try like:

1. Export/Import
2. Content deployment
3. [Cross-site publishing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635883.aspx) (new)

If you're using SharePoint 2013, be sure to check out cross site publishing!

In any case, you'll still have to deploy your customizations to both sides.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Isn't content deployment really a deploy of content and not only structure? Is there a risk when using content deployment that I delete existing content on the production site?

Comment: When using content deployment, you can't touch anything in production anymore or you'll run into problems. This is best suited for staging > production publishing scenario's. What are your requirements?

Comment: Requirements are kleeping content as is on the target production site and deploy changes to structure such as new sites/site collections - changes to navigation and overall structure of SharePoint instances, without the use of custom code (.wsp projects).

Comment: Content deployment uses the export/import API's that require a blank starting site. No manual modifications in the target site are supported :/ I think you're looking at custom code or 3rd party tools here.

Comment: I would say that Cross-site publishing solves the problem, where you can have an OOTB Authoring site. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Interesting question, do you have any feedback on this export from a production env ? I have to do this, and I thought using PowerShell (Export-SPWeb), but I'm afraid of the disk space it will use ...